# Batch Command to catch all possible ping issues

Tags: batch-file

I have a question regarding verifying that a ping is returning properly in a batch command.  Currently I have to check a ping 3 different ways to know that the server is in fact up.  I want to combine these into one single ping command.  I have tried using different error levels or not errorlevel 0 etc.  None of them catch all possible scenarios.  Here is what I have been using:

```
Set /p domain=Enter IP address:
set state=up

@ping.exe -n 1 %domain% | find "unreachable" > null && set state=down
if "%state%" == "down" goto :NoServer

@ping.exe -n 1 %domain% | find "TTL expired" > null && set state=down
if "%state%" == "down" goto :NoServer

@ping.exe -n 1 %domain%
if errorlevel 1 goto :NoServer
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to check the sucess or failure of the ping command: test the errorlevel after execution or test the output of the command. For both cases, it is not the same to check a ipv4 or a ipv6 address.

The questions are: how does `ping` behave?, what is its output? when is `errorlevel` set?

**The `errorlevel`**

If we are working with ipv6, the rules are

- `errorlevel` is set when there is no reply for all of the sent packets (all packets are lost)
- `errorlevel` is not set if there is a reply to any of the sent packets

ipv6 has a consistent behaviour and checking the errorlevel is a reliable way to know if the machine is online.

In ipv4 the rules are different

- `errorlevel` is set when there is no reply to at least one of the sent packets
- `errorlevel` is not set when there is a reply to all of the sent packets (no packet lost)

But, in ipv4, pinging an non available machine on the same subnet does no set the `errorlevel`, you get an "unreachable" answer, with `n packets sent, n packed received, 0 packets lost`, all the packets get a reply from the same machine sending the packets.

This behaviour in ipv4 when the machine is in the same subnet makes the errorlevel check fail.

**How to solve the problem in ipv4? Output check**

The output of the `ping` command can be checked, if the string `TTL=` is present in the output, the target machine is online.

```dos
ping -n 1 10.0.0.1 | find "TTL=" >nul 
if errorlevel 1 ( 
    echo offline 
) else (
    echo online
)
```

But this approach that works in ipv4 will fail with ipv6 as this field has not been included in the ping output (and renamed, in ipv6 it is called *hop limit*)

---

For a "general" solution, this (adapted from a previous answer) can be used (seems a lot of code, but almost all are comments). The `ping` operation and output handling are wrapped inside a subroutine that is called with the address/host name passed as the first argument to the batch file.

```dos
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    if "%~1"=="" goto :eof

    call :isOnline "%~1"
    if not errorlevel 1 ( echo ONLINE ) else ( echo OFFLINE )

    endlocal
    exit /b

:isOnline address pingCount
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: send only one ping packed unless it is indicated to send more than one
    set /a "pingCount=0", "pingCount+=%~2" >nul 2>nul 
    if %pingCount% lss 1 set "pingCount=1"

    :: a temporary file is needed to capture ping output for later processing
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    :: ping the indicated address getting command output and errorlevel
    ping -w 1000 -n %pingCount% "%~1" > "%tempFile%"  && set "pingError=" || set "pingError=1"

    ::
    :: When pinging, the behaviours of ipv4 and ipv6 are different
    ::
    :: we get errorlevel = 1 when
    ::    ipv4 - when at least one packet is lost. When sending more than one packet
    ::           the easiest way to check for reply is search the string "TTL=" in 
    ::           the output of the command.
    ::    ipv6 - when all packet are lost.
    ::
    :: we get errorlevel = 0 when
    ::    ipv4 - all packets are received. BUT pinging a inactive host on the same  
    ::           subnet result in no packet lost. It is necessary to check for "TTL=" 
    ::           string in the output of the ping command
    ::    ipv6 - at least one packet reaches the host
    ::
    :: We can try to determine if the input address (or host name) will result in 
    :: ipv4 or ipv6 pinging, but it is easier to check the result of the command
    ::
    ::                          +--------------+-------------+
    ::                          | TTL= present |    No TTL   | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
    ::  | ipv4    errorlevel 0  |      OK      |    ERROR    |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |      OK      |    ERROR    | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+ 
    ::  | ipv6    errorlevel 0  |              |      OK     |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |              |    ERROR    |
    ::  +-----------------------+----------------------------+
    ::
    :: So, if TTL= is present in output, host is online. If TTL= is not present,  
    :: errorlevel is 0 and the address is ipv6 then host is online. In the rest 
    :: of the cases host is offline.
    ::
    :: To determine the ip version, a regular expresion to match a ipv6 address is 
    :: used with findstr. As it will be only tested in the case of no errorlevel, 
    :: the ip address will be present in ping command output.

    set "exitCode=1"
    >nul 2>nul (
        find "TTL=" "%tempFile%" && ( set "exitCode=0" ) || (
            if not defined pingError (
                findstr /r /c:" [a-f0-9:][a-f0-9]*:[a-f0-9:%%]*[a-f0-9]: " "%tempFile%" && set "exitCode=0"
            )
        )
        del /q "%tempFile%"
    )

    :: cleanup and return errorlevel: 0=online , 1=offline 
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It seems like it is more lengthening than shortening my original test.  It is very informative though.  I am just starting to mess around with batch commands.

Comment: @Konan, it will be longer if you don't know a priori if you are testing a ipv4 or a ipv6 address/host name. If you only need ipv4, use the `find "TTL="` method. If you only need ipv6 use `errorlevel`. The problem is having to handle both

Comment: I see, I think I think I am pinging all ipv4 so I will just revise it to find "ttl=" and "unreachable"  That should catch all of the issues I hope.

Comment: @Konan, no need to check for "unreachable". For ipv4 if there is no `TTL=` in the output, the machine is offline. If `TTL=` is present, the machine is online.

Answer (score 0):

```
ping.exe -n 1 %domain% >tempfile
if not errorlevel 1 (
 findstr /i /c"unreachable" /c:"TTL expired" > null
 if errorlevel 1 goto :OK
)

:Noserver
```

should replicate your test using a single ping. I'm not sure whether `ping` returns errorlevel non-zero for all error conditions, or possibly one of your target strings and errorlevel 0. You'd need to specify.

Comment: what does >tempfile do?  I'd assume it creates a temp file but why?

Comment: `>` is a `redirector`. In the same way as `|` redirects output from a command as input for the next, `>` redirects output to a new file (or replaces an existing file) `>>`redirects output to a new file (or appends it an existing file) and `<` redirects input from a file instead of from the keyboard.