# skip a computers in a batch file that is unreachable

Tags: batch-file

when the script is running, when it finds a machine to be unreachable I want it to skip it. and do psexec command for the online PCs only

i created a bat file as below but it's not working

```
 @echo off
setlocal
:begin
for /f %%a in (computerlist.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 %%a >NUL 2>NUL
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        psexec \\%%a -u user -p password -i -d "d:\path\command.exe"
    ) else echo Skipping unreachable host %%a
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748080/2861476) could help

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic /node:"@computerlist.txt" /failfast:on process call create "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

It doesn't wait for computers that don't answer quickly. Notepad will be invisible on remote machine but not a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your code and access the errorlevel as `!errorlevel!`:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in (computerlist.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 %%a >NUL 2>NUL
    if !errorlevel!==0 (
        psexec \\%%a -u user -p password -i -d "d:\path\command.exe"
    ) else echo Skipping unreachable host %%a
)
```

The problem is that usually variables are being evaluated at parse time. So if you use `%errorlevel%` it will always contain the first set value. `EnableDelayedExpansion` will force evaluation at execution time instead so `!errorlevel!` will always contain the last assigned value (while %errorlevel% will still contain the first one). In your case the variable might change on **each iteration of the loop** so you obviously need `!errorlevel!`.

For more information check http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html.