# Batch Random Pinging(Trying to determine if a ping is successful)

Tags: batch-file, random, ip, ping

I have made a program that creates random IPs and pings them to see if they exist. It records the output using '>' and '>>'. I want to check if the ping times out and if it does exclude it from the text document. This is my code so far:

```
`@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
 SET /A N1=%RANDOM% * 255 / 32768
 SET /A N2=%RANDOM% * 255 / 32768
 SET /A N3=%RANDOM% * 255 / 32768
 SET /A N4=%RANDOM% * 255 / 32768
 PING %N1%.%N2%.%N3%.%N4%>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\IP.txt"
 GOTO LOOP`
```

After the ping is done I want it to record IPs that respond, not the ones that time out.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /l %%a in (0) do (
        set /a  "A=!random! %% 255", ^
                "B=!random! %% 255", ^
                "C=!random! %% 255", ^
                "D=!random! %% 255"

        ping -w 1000 -n 1 "!A!.!B!.!C!.!D!" | find "TTL=" > nul && (
            >>"online.txt" echo !A!.!B!.!C!.!D!
        )
    )
```

This creates and infinite loop (this `for /l %%a in (0)` means `for %%a starting in 0 up to 0 in steps of 0`)

For each iteration, four random numbers are generated for each of the the ip address octects. To do it, we generate a random number usign the build in `!random!` variable ([delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) is needed) and get remainder of the division by 255 (modulo operator is `%%` in batch files) using a `set /a` command, the batch way of doing calcs.

Once the ip is generated (more delayed expansion, see previously linked answer), a ping is sent and its output checked for the presence of the `TTL=` string ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27748080/2861476)). If this string is present, the target is reachable and the address is appended to a file.

To test if the string is present in the output of the `ping` command, it is piped into a `find` command searching for the indicated string. If the string is found `errorlevel` variable is set to 0, if it is not found, `errorlevel` will be set to 1.

This value is checked using conditional execution operator `&&`. This means *if the previous command does not set the `errorlevel` to anything greater than 0, then execute the next command*.

So, if the `find` command finds the string, `errorlevel` will not be 1 and the `echo` command will be executed. This `echo` is redirected to append to target file (`>>` is an append redirection)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set the number of IP's to test
set num=20

echo Creating and testing %num% IP's
echo/

for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do (

   rem Create the random IP
   set /A N1=!random! %% 255, N2=!random! %% 255, N3=!random! %% 255, N4=!random! %% 255
   set "IP=!N1!.!N2!.!N3!.!N4!"

   rem Show the IP and leave the cursor after it
   set /P "=%%i- Testing !IP!: " < NUL

   rem Test the IP with ping and get just the 3rd word of the 3rd line from ping output
   set "word="
   for /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%a in ('ping !IP!') do if not defined word set "word=%%a"

   rem If that word is not "out", the IP is correct
   if "!word!" neq "out" (
      echo CORRECT
      echo !IP!>> IP.txt
   ) else (
      echo failed...
   )

)
```

Comment: Could you explain this to me? As I said before I'm a bit new and I don't know some of these commands.