# How do I make an If event in batch when a ping fails?

Tags: batch-file

I know this has been asked many times before but it's a bit different in my situation.

"If errorlevel 1" does not work in my case

When I ping something like my router when my ethernet is unpluged than it won't return a "timeout" it will return a "general failure" the statement "if errorlevel 1" won't detect it so I'm getting a response saying that it's reachable when it's not and it won't detect the "general failure" as an error.

I was thinking maybe it's possible to make a line checking the response (in ascii) to check if it's "General Failure" but I wouldn't know how to do that either.

Is there a way to get past this problem or is this the limit of batch?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748080/2861476) could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
ping "www.whatever.com" && echo OK || echo Connection Problem
```

for more explaination :

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: What is the `&&` and `||` priority? Statements like these always confuse me because of the lack of parenthesis.

Comment: There is no priority. The statement after  `&&` will be displayed if the errorlevel is [<= 0] and the statement after `||` will be displayed if the errorlevel  [>=1]. You can also use parenthesis if you will do more think. `ping "www.whatever.com" && (do what you want) || (do what you want)`

Comment: This does not work in all cases. Please, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748080/2861476)